# Nesting a max(date) statement in a mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm having difficult with the logic/syntax surrounding a nested 'select max(date)' style statement. Let me try to explain. I have three tables that my statement is pulling data from:

Table #1 (table1_companies)
[id, companyname, industry]

Table #2: (table2_companydata)
[id, companyname, data, date_added]

Table #3: (table3_watchlist)
[id, companyname, usernane]

The statement I'm attempting to execute takes a company name from the Table 3, INNER JOINS the 'industry' from Table 1 and then INNER JOINS the latest company info (based on the last date) from Table 2. It is Table 2 that can have many rows per company, I just need the last one based on the latest date that was added. My current (simplified) statement without the attempt to grab the last date is:

```
SELECT 
table1_companies.industry, 
table2_companydata.data, 
table3_watchlist.* 

FROM 
table3_watchlist 
INNER JOIN table1_companies ON table1_companies.companyname =          table3_watchlist.companyname INNER JOIN table2_companydata ON table2_companydata.companyname = table3_watchlist.companyname WHERE   username='username'");
```

I think I need to insert a "SELECT max(date_added) FROM table2_companydata" into the 2nd INNER JOIN. But I've had no success with either logic or syntax. Can any enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Do the `join`s and *then* select the last record.  Here is one method using a `where` clause for the logic:

```
SELECT c.industry, cd.data, w.* 
FROM table3_watchlist w INNER JOIN 
     table1_companies c
     ON c.companyname = w.companyname INNER JOIN
     table2_companydata cd
     ON cd.companyname = w.companyname
WHERE username = 'username' AND
      cd.date_added = (select max(cd2.date_added)
                       from table2_companydata cd2
                       where cd2.companyname = cd.companyname
                      );
```